# Web3 Provider not available. Use `.setProvider` or `.provider=` to initialize the provider

Tags: web3js, javascript

Modified today
Viewed 2 times
0

Hi i cain't get my code to work as it use to a few months back and I caint figure out why can anyone support I appreciate it, I tried a few things but none worked.

I would like to simply be able to interact with a smart contract from my js frontend

I get this error when trying to call the mint method

`Provider not available. Use .setProvider or .provider= to initialize the provider`

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {useMetaMaskWallet} from 'vue-connect-wallet';
import {ABI, ADDRESS} from './util/constants/contract';
import {Web3} from 'web3';

const wallet = useMetaMaskWallet();
const $toast = useToast();

export default {
    data: () => {
        return {
            loading: false,
            metamaskAddress: '',
            contract: null,
            web3: null,
        };
    },
    async created() {
        const {ethereum} = window;
        if (!ethereum) {
            return;
        }
        const localInstance = new Web3(ethereum);
        this.web3 = localInstance;
        this.contract = new localInstance.eth.Contract(ABI, ADDRESS);
    },
    methods: {
        async connectWallet() {
            const accounts = await wallet.connect();
            this.metamaskAddress = accounts[0];
            // check if the address is on the whitelist
            // check if the address already minted
        },

        async mint() {
            if (this.loading) return;
            try {
                this.loading = true;

                const url = 'http://localhost:8888/.netlify/functions/sign';
                const res = await axios.post(url, {
                    address: this.metamaskAddress,
                });

                if (!res.data.signature) {
                    this.loading = false;
                    return this.showErrorMessage('Invalid signature');
                }
                console.log(res.data.signature);
                await this.contract.methods
                    .mint(res.data.signature)
                    .estimateGas({
                        from: this.metamaskAddress,
                        value: 0,
                    });
                await this.contract.methods.mint(res.data.signature).send({
                    from: this.metamaskAddress,
                    value: 0,
                });
                this.loading = false;
            } catch (e) {
                this.loading = false;
                return this.showErrorMessage(e);
            }
    },
};
```